# NSIS Permission not working as expected for "Users"

Tags: nsis

I have searched almost many posts and articles. But not helping me with this.

I'm trying to add permission to the $APPDATA\MY_APP\conf directory. I have observed the command is not working properly with multiple machines.

Any suggestions, as to why this below command is behaving differently on 2 different laptops? Both laptops are having Windows 10 Enterprise and Windows 10 Home edition. What mistake am I'm doing?

```
SetShellVarContext all  
;Before Permission
nsExec::ExecToLog '"icacls" "$appDataDir\conf"'
Pop $0
AccessControl::GrantOnFile  "$appDataDir\conf" "(BU)" "FullAccess"
;After Permission
nsExec::ExecToLog '"icacls" "$appDataDir\conf"'
Pop $0
```

**Laptop 1:** Working on this laptop. The "Users" option is visible on the folder level.

[image]

[image]

**Laptop 2:** It's not working on the laptop, I can see on folder permission also "Users" is not visible.

[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Edit:-
If I add this below permission manually its works fine. How to add only this below permission on NSIS?
[image]

Comment: Is it failing on the Enterprise laptop? Also, doing this is not recommended and indicates a design problem with your application.

Comment: Failing with Home edition. Do you mean design problem in my nsis script ? Any suggestion how to fix ?

Comment: No, I mean, giving all users full access to something in the programdata folder is not something you should be doing.

Comment: Ok. Even I tried with this AccessControl::GrantOnFile "$appDataDir\conf" "(S-1-5-32-545)" "FullAccess"

Comment: The permissions are the recommended values by default, you should not be using GrantOnFile on anything in $appdata.

Comment: Let me remove  and try.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250989/discussion-between-jdguide-and-anders).

Comment: Even after removing all GrantOnFile for $appData , still not working.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by not working but your app should not write there, only the installer. Does your installer have `RequestExecutionLevel admin`?

Comment: Yes, RequestExecutionLevel admin is enabled. Actually during installation 2 new files are getting created inside appdata/conf directory  by some other java jar. Those 2 files are causing the issue.

Comment: Finally adding permission manually this testapp.properties file working fine.                                                 `AccessControl::GrantOnFile   "$appDataDir\conf\testapp.properties" "(BU)" "FullAccess"`. But, I am surprise I have the below statement which is giving the same permission to $appDataDir/conf , then why is this testapp.properties file not getting applied with the required permission? i.e. `AccessControl::GrantOnFile   "$appDataDir\conf" "(BU)" "FullAccess"`. The $appDataDir/conf directory has 4 files only 1 file is getting updated with the expected permission.

Comment: AccessControl::EnableFileInheritance on the directory?

Comment: @Anders, Even I have tried this. WilI rechcek again. Thank you.